# Use array valued function as argument to another function

Tags: arrays, fortran, parameter-passing, fortran90

I have transformed a problem from a more complex f90-code into the following:

```
module userfunctions

implicit none

contains

    function Function1(Argument,ArgumentSize)

        ! Input
        integer, intent(in)                         ::      ArgumentSize
        real,dimension(ArgumentSize),intent(in)     ::      Argument

        ! Output
        real,dimension(ArgumentSize)                ::      Function1    

        ! Local
        integer                 ::      i

        Function1 = Argument

        ! Random operation on argument, resembling generic vector function
        do i=1,ArgumentSize

            Function1(i) = Function1(i)**2

        end do

    end function Function1


    function Function2(RandomFunction,Argument,ArgumentSize)


    ! Input
    integer, intent(in)                         ::      ArgumentSize
    real,dimension(ArgumentSize), intent(in)    ::      Argument

    ! Array-type function of dimension ArgumentSize
    real,external                       ::      RandomFunction

    ! Evaluate RandomFunction to
    real,dimension(ArgumentSize)       ::      Value

    ! Output
    real                                ::      Function2

    ! assign evaluation of RandomFunction to Value
    Value = RandomFunction(Argument,ArgumentSize)

    Function2 = dot_product(Value,Value)

    end function Function2

end module userfunctions



    program Fortran_Console_002

        use userfunctions

        implicit none

        real                    ::      Result1
        real,dimension(6)       ::      Vector1

        Vector1 = 2

        Result1 = Function2(Function1,Vector1,6)

        write(*,*) Result1


    end program Fortran_Console_002
```

The result should be "96". Compiling this with Visual Studio 2013 and Intel Fortran produces the following error:

> Error 1    error #6634: The shape matching rules of actual arguments and
>   dummy arguments have been violated.   [FUNCTION1]

In real context I do need to pass an array-valued function from a subroutine to a function defined in a module (a solver for nonlinear functions which takes functions as arguments). I do know how to do this for a scalar-valued function, but failed to apply this to an array.

I use Visual Studio 2013 for this because of convenience. The real piece has to be compiled using Compaq Visual Fortran 6 on a virtual machine which is, as of my knowledge, only compatible up to fortran90.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See   [How to pass subroutine names as arguments in Fortran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32809769/how-to-pass-subroutine-names-as-arguments-in-fortran/32811182#32811182) for general rules.

Don't use `external` here. It is incompatible with advanced features like array valued functions. Generally, `external` is only for old programs in FORTRAN 77 style.  Make an interface block (see the link) or try

```
   procedure(Function1) :: RandomFunction
```

instead (Fortran 2003).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It didn't do the trick immediately but totally pushed me in the right direction.