# How to pass function in array in fortran?

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran

Method of dealing with symbolic variable function in fortran
I have question about passing a defined array into another function. Here is sample code.

`!file saved as test5.f08`

```
module test5

    implicit none
    contains

    function f1 (arr1) result (sum_arr)
        real, dimension (:), allocatable, intent (in):: arr1 
        real, dimension (3):: arr2
        real :: sum_arr
        integer :: index

        sum_arr=0
        arr2 = [4,5,6]

        do index= 1,3
            arr1(index) = index  !------Q2-----------
            sum_arr = sum_arr + ( arr1(index)*arr2(index) + arr2(index))
        end do

    end function f1

end module test5
```

Main program calling above module:

`!file saved as test5_call.f08`

```
program test5_call
    use test5
    implicit none

    integer :: n
    real,  allocatable, dimension (:) :: array1
    real::xvar, answer

    allocate (array1(3))
    array1 = [xvar,xvar*2,xvar*xvar] !---------Q1-------

    answer = f1(array1)
    print *,"Answer of array elements  = ", answer

end program test5_call
```

Compiling as
`gfortran test5.f08 test5_call.f08 -o test5_call`

In the line Q1 in the main program, I am defining an array containing math expression $[x, x^2, X^3]$ I want to pass this array to function f1 in module test5. In line Q2 (in function f1 in module test5), I want to evaluate this array expression. So when `index=2`, `arr1 = [2, 2^2, 2^3]`.

Basically I want to pass array with (symbolic variable) expression to a function. And evaluate the expression in the function, where the expression will receive values.

This code runs, but there is no effect of array function. Any help how to do this?

I tried searching on this, but didn't get any information. In C, I found a link [How do you pass a function as a parameter in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410/how-do-you-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-c) . As I do not have much knowledge about C, I am not sure whether the technique in the question should be used.

Answer (score 2):

### What your present code is doing:

`xvar` is just a real number

`array1 = [xvar,xvar*2,xvar*xvar]` is just an array of three real numbers, the value will depend on the current value of `xvar` which is undefined in your code.

`real, dimension (:), allocatable, intent (in):: arr1` is again just an allocatable array of several real numbers. Note, that you do not need `allocatable` here at all.

---

### How to do what you intended:

First, you should study how to pass functions at all, see among others

[How to pass subroutine names as arguments in Fortran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32809769/how-to-pass-subroutine-names-as-arguments-in-fortran)

That way you can pass one function. I would suggest you to start there and declare your `f1` to accept three separate functions

```
function f1 (func1, func2, func3) result (sum_arr)
  abstract interface
    real function arg_func(x)
      real, intent(in) :: x
    end function
  end interface

  procedure(arg_func) :: func1, func2, func3
```

Only after you understand how this work and after you are confident using procedure arguments in general you can start thinking about using an array.

You would have to define a container which contains a procedure pointer and use an array of these containers. It is an advanced topic, leave it for the future [Function pointer arrays in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521072/function-pointer-arrays-in-fortran)

Comment: I guess you meant to end your `end interface` before `end function`. By the way, why did you create abstract interface? And what is `procedure(arg_func) :: func1, func2, func3`?

Comment: Is there any special purpose to create it abstract interface? I am bit confused in studying the topic you pointed out. Therefore, any good reference is welcome too.

Comment: Yes, the purpose is to safe typing and to reuse the single interface for all three functions. You could just create a separate non-abstract interface to the functions and avoid the procedure declaration.